# How to cast from object to Generic List in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting

I have a script that needs to **compare all sorts of values**, and one thing I need it to do is to compare a value from a List to a value from another list. But since the **script has to work with pretty much any type**, I'm boxing the values into objects.

Now my problem is this:
**How do I cast from an object to a Generic List of a certain type?**
And how do I then get the Length of that list and retrieve elements from that list?

Here's my attempt of getting that to work:

```
Type type;
int subElement;
object value; //holds the value

public virtual bool CompareValue( object val ) { //compare value against val
     //LIST
     if( type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( List<> ) ) {
            if( subElement == -2 ) { //Compare against COUNT
                var listType = typeof( List<> );
                var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType( type.GetGenericArguments()[0] ); //get the type inside the list
                var listVal = Convert.ChangeType( val, constructedListType );
                val = listVal.Count; //DOES NOT WORK :(
                return value == val;
            } else if( subElement >= 0 ) { //Compare against SPECIFIC ELEMENT
                tempType = tempType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; //Get the type inside the List
                List<object> list = ((List<object>)val); //DOES NOT WORK
                if( list.Count >= subElement ) return false;
                val = Convert.ChangeType( list[subElement], tempType );
                return value == val;
            }
      } //else if other types, etc., etc.
}
```

First use-case:

```
 type = typeof( List<string> ); //In reality I'm getting this via Reflection
 subElement = -2; //makes it compare length of Lists
 value = 3;
 bool match = CompareValue( new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three"} ); //should return true since the length of the list is 3
```

Second use-case - compare specific element:

```
 type = typeof( List<int> ); //In reality I'm getting this via Reflection
 subElement = 3; //compare the 3rd element in the list
 value = 7f;
 bool match = CompareValue( new List<float>() { 3f, 4.5f, 7f, 10.4f, 22.6f } ); //should return true because the value of the 3rd element is 7f
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you just need to cast to `System.Collections.IList`.

Comment: What is the type of `var` in `var listVal = Convert.ChangeType( val, constructedListType );`?

Comment: Instead of putting `DOES NOT WORK`, put why it doesn't work, exception? Silently fails? etc... Create a [MCVE].

Comment: @Lee Ah! With that I got the the Count to work!
     IList v = (IList) val;
     val = v.Count;

Comment: @JacobKrall That's kind of my problem. I want to just do List<typeVar> myList = (List<typeVar>)val; but that doesn't work...

Comment: With IList I made the second case work as well! I just cast to an IList and get the value: IList l = (IList) val; l[subElement]; Thanks @Lee!

Answer (score 0):

You can try two approaches:

Using dynamic:

```
dynamic listVal = Convert.ChangeType( val, constructedListType );
val = listVal.Count;
```

Or using reflection:

```
val = constructedListType.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(value);
```

In your example, `listVal.Count` wouldn't even compile, as `listVal` is an `object` returned by `Convert.ChangeType` and does not have such property.